# WiXToolset (Burn) : Text disappears on pressing alt key

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I noticed something strange while running WiX Burn installer. After pressing Alt key, the text gets disappeared somehow and doesn't appear back.

I have placed an image and a custom text over it in HyperLinkTheme.xml :

```
<Image X="0" Y="0" Width="460" Height="180" ImageFile="image.jpg" Visible="yes"/>
<Text X="22" Y="70" Width="300" Height="30" FontId="5" Visible="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">Setup</Text>
```

Rest all remains intact in the page, just this heading disappears. I am not able to get the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It's an open bug that someone needs to fix - https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4931.

Comment: Is it open since 2015? How much time are we looking at?